# Looping Through Multiple Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I have multiple arrays of instances of `ActiveRecord` subclass `Item` that I need to loop through an print in accordance to earliest event. In this case, I need to print print out payment and maintenance dates as follows:

> Item A maintenance required in 5 days
>   Item B payment required in 6 days
>   Item A payment required in 7 days
>   Item B maintenance required in 8 days

I currently have two queries for finding `maintenance` and `payment` items (non-exclusive query) and something like the following to output them:

```
<%- item_p = nil -%>
<%- item_m = nil -%>

<%- loop do -%>
  <% item_p ||= @items_p.shift %>
  <% item_m ||= @items_m.shift %>

  <%- if item_p.nil? and item_m.nil? then break -%>
  <%- elsif item_p and (item_m.nil? or item_p.paymt < item_m.maint) then -%>
    <%= item_p.name %> payment required in ...
  <%- elsif item_m and (item_p.nil? or item_m.maint < item_p.paymt) then -%>
    <%= item_m.name %> maintenance required in ...
  <%- end -%>
<%- end -%>
```

Any way to cleanup the readability of the above (ugly) code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quick and dirty (i.e. not optimized):

```
# In your controller:
@items = @items_p.map{ |item| {:item => item, :days => item.paymt, :description => "payment"} } 
@items += @items_m.map{ |item| {:item => item, :days => item.maint, :description => "maintenance"} }
@items = @items.sort_by{ |item| item[:day] }

# In your view:
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item[:item].name %> <%= item[:description] %> required in <%= item[:days] %> days
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

Embrace duck-typing and make sure that your objects are **polymorphic**. You want your *payment* items to be **comparable** with *maintenance* items, in order to sort them.

So, suppose you have a `Payment` and a `Maintenance` class:

```
module Due
  include Comparable

  # Compare this object with another. Used for sorting.
  def <=>(other)
    self.due <=> other.due
  end
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Due

  alias_method :due, :payment

  def action
    "#{name} requires payment"
  end
end

class Maintenance < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Due

  alias_method :due, :maintenance

  def action
    "#{name} requires maintenance"
  end
end
```

See how we create an `action`, `due` and `<=>` method in **both** classes? We also took care to include the Ruby built-in module `Comparable`. This allows us to do the following:

```
# Assuming 'payment' and 'maintenance' are date fields...
a = Payment.new :payment => 3.days.from_now
b = Maintenance.new :maintenance => 2.days.from_now
[a, b].sort
#=> [b, a]
```

The view then becomes as simple as:

```
<% (@payment_items + @maintenance_items).sort.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.action %> in <%= distance_of_time_in_words_to_now(item.due) %><br/>
<% end %>
```

I'm sure I haven't got the details of your implementation right, but I hope this gives you an idea of how to approach your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my current model is a `Item` that has both attributes `required` and `payment` (as dates). Will this still work? As seen in my example, Item A appears for both maintenance and payment. In this case, said item has an 'anniversary' at which payment is required and an 'anniversary' at which maintenance is required on said item.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing way too much in your view. Really you should figure out all of this in the controller and pass through a cleaned up structure that you can iterate over for display purposes.

As an example:

```
length = [ @items_p.length, @items_m.length ].sort.last

@messages = [ ]

length.times do |i|
  item_p = @items_p[i]
  item_m = @items_m[i]

  if (item_p and (item_m and item_p.paymt < item_m.maint) or !item_m)
    @messages << "#{item_p.name} payment required in ..."
  elsif (item_m and (item_p and item_m.maint < item_p.paymt) or !item_p)
    @messages << "#{item_m.name} maintenance required in ..."
  end
end
```

You would then iterate over `@messages` as required.

The real problem here is that you haven't structured these objects for this sort of thing strategically speaking. It would be nice if you had a single method for the due date instead of having to differentiate between `paymt` and `maint` according to the type. Likewise, it would be better if both of these were paired up into an Array instead of supplied separately.

If you had them in `[ p, m ]` pairs you could iterate much more simply:

```
items.each do |pair|
  first_due = pair.compact.sort_by(&:due).first
  @messages << "#{first_due.name} #{first_due.action} required in ..."
end
```

The `action` method would return `payment` or `maintenance` as required.

Comment: In my opinion, you don't want to do this in your controller either.

Comment: @molf This looks like 'fat controller' (which I've heard is to be avoided). In this case should I be doing that in the model instead Thanks!

Comment: There's degrees of refactoring, from view to controller, and later, if you can find a good pattern, from controller to model, absolutely. I just have no idea what these models are all about, though. There are different schools of thinking on where to put the heavy lifting, either model or controller, which probably depends on your OO-background. Rails tends towards heavier models.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Appreciate it!